# How can I take one column of a csv and move it to another column while matching each row of the column to the proper name?

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files. CSV 1 contains usernames and their group name. CSV 2 contains usernames, what MFA they use, and a few other irrelevant columns.

I want to take the Group names from CSV1, and add them as a column to CSV2. However, they aren't in the same order so some name sorting has to happen and I can't figure it out.

Example of CSV1:

```
Group Name      Username
Member          Bob.Joe
Support         Mike.House
Support         Annie.Naym
Member          Fayke.Nayme
Security        Anutha.Name
```

Example of CSV 2:

```
Name        Login       MFA
Joe Schmo   joe.schmo   Type1
Bob Joe     bob.joe     Type2
Mike House  mike.house  Type2
Randum Guy  randum.guy  Type1
Annie Naym  annie,naym  Type2
Fayke Nayme fayke.name  Type2
Anutha.Name anutha.name Type2
```

And I would want the output to be:

```
Name        Login       MFA     Group Name
Joe Schmo   joe.schmo   Type1   
Bob Joe     bob.joe     Type2   Member
Mike House  mike.house  Type2   Support
Randum Guy  randum.guy  Type1   
Annie Naym  annie,naym  Type2   Support
Fayke Nayme fayke.name  Type2   Member
Anutha.Name anutha.name Type2   Security
```

Comment: Uhh, I don't know how? That's the entire basis of the question

Comment: Check out the Python csv library and try some code. stackoverflow is not a tutorial or code writing service. We can help with specific problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. Again, please see [ask].

Comment: you can use standard module `csv` to read data and later create `for`-loops to check and add data from one table to other table (row-by-row). Or you can use `pandas` to do it without `for`-loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df2['group name'] = df2.login.map(df1.set_index('username')['Group'])
```

output I got

```
    Name    login   MFA group name
0   joe schmo   jeo.schmo   T1  NaN
1   bob joe     bob.joe     T2  member
2   mike house  mike.house  T1  support
3   random guy  randum.guy  NaN NaN
4   annie nayam annie.nayam T1  support
5   fayke nayme fayke.name  T2  NaN
6   anutha.name anutha.name T1  security
```